# Move images during PowerPoint slide show

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I'm currently working on an interactive PowerPoint game for my students, in which I need to move six images (i.e. the students' tokens) around freely. Is there any way to achieve this with the help of VBA?

Comment: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_powerpoint-mso_other-mso_2010/how-can-i-make-powerpoint-interactive-in/c2d49984-7761-e011-8dfc-68b599b31bf5

Comment: Unfortunately, the code provided doesn't seem to be working for me. When I have clicked the shaped and click for its new location, the presentation moves to the next slide.

Comment: We can't help you if you don't post the code you're using.

Comment: I've tried the code found on http://officeoneonline.com/vba/mousemove_shape.html, but even the demo presentation isn't working for me (see above).

Comment: Just found out the code only works with Windows. Such a shame.